# kubernetes: deploying kong helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kong

I deploy kong via helm on my kubernetes cluster but I can't configure it as I want.

```
helm install stable/kong -f values.yaml
```

value.yaml:

```
{
   "persistence.size":"1Gi",
   "persistence.storageClass":"my-kong-storage"
}
```

Unfortunately, the created persistenceVolumeClaim stays at 8G instead of 1Gi. Even adding "persistence.enabled":false has no effect on deployment. So I think my all my configuration is bad.

What should be a good configuration file?

I am using kubernetes rancher deployment on bare metal servers.
I use Local Persistent Volumes. (working well with mongo-replicaset deployment)

Comment: I think that kong chart does not have a storage configuration that you can customize. can you review the chart to ensure that ?

Comment: kong/chart/postgresql/values.yaml contain persistence config, I saw it on rancher but not on the helm/kong repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to configure a dependency chart (a.k.a subchart ) which is a little different from a main chart when it comes to writing `values.yaml`. Here is how you can do it:

As `postgresql` is a dependency chart for `kong` so you have to use the name of the dependency chart as a key then the rest of the options you need to modify in the following form:

> The content of `values.yaml` does not need to be surrounded with curly braces. so you need to remove it from the code you posted in the question.

```yaml
<dependcy-chart-name>:
  <configuration-key-name>: <configuration-value>
```

For Rancher you have to write it as the following:

```yaml
#values.yaml for rancher
postgresql.persistence.storageClass: "my-kong-storage"
postgresql.persistence.size: "1Gi"
```

Unlike if you are using helm itself with vanilla kubernetes - at least - you can write the `values.yml` as below:

```yaml
#values.yaml for helm
postgresql:
  persistence:
    storageClass: "my-kong-storage"
    size: "1Gi"
```

> - More about [Dealing with SubChart values](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals.md#overriding-values-of-a-child-chart)
> - More about [Postgresql chart configuration](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql#configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Please tell us which cluster setup you are using. A cloud managed service? Custom setup kubernetes?

The problem you are facing is that there is a "minimum size" of storage to be provisioned. For example in IBM Cloud it is 20 GB. 
So even if 2GB are requested in the PVC , you will end up with a 20GB PV.

Please check the documentation of your NFS Provisioner / Storage Class

Comment: I add configuration details. I figure my problem is I don't configure chart correctly.